# C TCP Socket recv return -1 on Server-Server communication

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, send, recv

I am building a `client-server socket` simulation to emulate `DHCP`. I have a `client` that receives input from the user, then sends a request via `UDP` to `Server1`. If Server1 does not hold the requested information, it contacts `Server2` via `TCP`. If `Server2` does not hold the information, it contacts `Server3`. `Server3` then sends information to `Server2` then `Server1` then on to the `Client`

My code works for `Client --> Server1 --> Server2 --> Server1 --> Client`, but it fails when I try to add `Server3`.

`Server3` successfully receives the connection and data from `Server2`, and the `send` is successful I believe. However, the `recv` on server 2 returns `-1`.

Here is my `Server3` send code:

```
while ((rqst = accept(svc,(struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &alen)) < 0) {
    /* we may break out of accept if the system call */
    /* was interrupted. In this case, loop back and */
    /* try again */
} 
inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr), ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
recvlen = recv(rqst, buf, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
if (send(rqst, "Hello Server2!\0", BUFSIZE, 0) < 0) { /* Not real message, but this works */
          perror("sendto");
}
```

My `Server2 recv` code is here

```
int port = SERVICE_PORT3;      /* default: whatever is in port.h */
char *host = "localhost";      /* default: this host */
if (!conn_and_send(host, port, buf, fd3)) {    /* connect fd3 is global int */
  exit(1);   /* something went wrong */
}
else {
  char serv3_buf[BUFSIZE];
  int serv3_recvlen = recv(fd3, serv3_buf, BUFSIZE - 1, 0);
  printf("The recv length from serv3 is: %d\n", serv3_recvlen); /* prints -1*/
}
```

This is my `conn_and_send` function

```
int conn_and_send(char *host, int port, char* request, int fd_sock)
{
  struct hostent *hp;   /* host information */
  unsigned int alen;    /* address length when we get the port number */
  struct sockaddr_in myaddr;    /* our address */
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr;  /* server address */

  printf("conn(host=\"%s\", port=\"%d\")\n", host, port);

  if ((fd_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("cannot create socket");
    return 0;
  }

  memset((char *)&myaddr, 0, sizeof(myaddr));
  myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  myaddr.sin_port = htons(0);

  if (bind(fd_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(myaddr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind failed");
    return 0;
  }

  alen = sizeof(myaddr);
  if (getsockname(fd_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, &alen) < 0) {
    perror("getsockname failed");
    return 0;
  }
  printf("local port number = %d\n", ntohs(myaddr.sin_port));

  memset((char*)&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(port);

  hp = gethostbyname(host);
  if (!hp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not obtain address of %s\n", host);
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy((void *)&servaddr.sin_addr, hp->h_addr_list[0], hp->h_length);

  if (connect(fd_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0) {
    perror("connect failed");
    return 0;
  }
  printf("Getting ready to send: %s\n", request);
  if (send(fd_sock, request, strlen(request), 0) < 0) {
    perror("sendto");
    exit(1);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Sorry to post so much code. I tried to include only relevant snippets.

What am I doing wrong, and if you can see no problems besides my poor `C` coding, why does `C` hate me?! :P

Comment: I think it's very hard to help you because of the complexity of your program, you need to use the best debugger that you can use to step through the code and check what's wrong, that's how I would solve this kind of problem, and I am pretty sure that it's everyone else's approach. Asking here should be for specific problems, yours is not IMHO.

Comment: @iharob Can you recommend a debugger?

Comment: It depends, what platform are you on?

Comment: `C` in a `Mac` terminal. I'm compiling with `gcc`

Comment: With **gcc** use **gdb**

Comment: @iharob BTW, did you not see anything grossly wrong with the code I posted

Comment: No, and I didn't look at it too much because it's hard to relate the problem to this code.